# Patchlist for Ubuntu kernels

Tags: kernel, patch

I am experiencing a known bug with OCFS2 and Linux 3.5 and I'm wondering how I can tell if the patch is in a specific Ubuntu kernel or not.

The exact patch is here: https://oss.oracle.com/git/?p=smushran/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=a2118b301104a24381b414bc93371d666fe8d43a

Its only a mild inconvenience so I don't want to recompile the kernel from scratch (mostly laziness) however I do want to know when I can upgrade to a kernel with the patch.

Googling hasn't come up with a easy way of telling. Does anyone know?

Comment: I should mention that I'm running "3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu" right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oracle patch](https://oss.oracle.com/git/?p=smushran/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=a2118b301104a24381b414bc93371d666fe8d43a) you mention wasn't accepted upstream as it was, but was tweaked by Luis Henriques of Canonical, as noted [here at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1006012), and was accepted into Linus Torvald's master branch of the kernel [in July 2012](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a4e08d001f2e50bb8b3c4eebadcf08e5535f02ee).

According to the [Launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1006012), the issue was fixed with kernel 3.5.0-3.3 for Quantal and kernel 3.2.0-27.43 for Precise. Both were issued as updates, and so there should be no need to use a mainline kernel or patch it yourself.

If you wish to look at the changelog for the currently installed kernel (which includes notes on previous changes to the 3.x.x series) you can run 
`uname -a`  to find your kernel, and then use its package name to get the changelog:

```
apt-get changelog 3.5.0-17-generic
```

You can `grep` it for your issue (using `-C` to show lines around the search term):

```
apt-get changelog 3.5.0-17-generic | grep -i -C 2 'ocfs2'
```

then you find the issue should have been fixed:

```
[ Luis Henriques ]

  * SAUCE: ocfs2: Fix NULL pointer dereferrence in
    __ocfs2_change_file_space
    - LP: #1006012
```

You could also grep the changelog for the Launchpad record for the issue (1006012), if you couldn't find the right part of the changelog. This change was first announced in the 3.5.0-3.3 Quantal release.

Other changelogs (for versions not installed) can be found on [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com).

If you think you are experiencing a regression, please add a comment at the [Launchpad page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1006012), and ask for clarification.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. Google wasn't much of a help here but you nailed it completely.